# How to add up values in a dataframe where columns have common part as elements in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in a format:

```
d = {'A_B': [1, 2], 'A_C': [3, 4], 'B_C': [5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

And a list

```
li=[A,B,C]
```

Now I want to add all elements in a row where column name begins with the element from a list and substract all elements where column ends with the element from a list.

The result would be:

```
index      A         B       C
0         1+3      -1+5    -3-5
1         2+3      -2+6    -4-6
```

How can I approach it?

Answer (score 1):

In your case we can do `split` for the column then combine them

```
s1 = df.copy()
s1.columns = s1.columns.str.split('_').str[0]
s2 = df.copy()
s2.columns = s2.columns.str.split('_').str[1]

out = pd.concat([s1,-s2],axis=1).groupby(level=0,axis=1).sum()
Out[468]: 
   A  B   C
0  4  4  -8
1  6  4 -10
```